# How to reference application files from within an AWS container_commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run a grunt build in the `container_commands` section of my `.ebextensions/init.config` file. The command in question looks like this:

```
10-run-grunt:
    command: $NODE_HOME/bin/node $NODE_HOME/bin/grunt --gruntfile /tmp/deploy/application/Gruntfile.js build
```

Since you would usually run the `grunt build` command from within the application root, which I'm unable to do from container_commands, you can see I'm specifying the path to the gruntfile using the `--gruntfile <path_to_gruntfile>` option.

My question is: how do you get the path to application files from within a `container_commands` command? I assume there is an environment variable which represents this.